# How to count the advertisement hits and stores it in database

Tags: java, javascript, web

We put our website advertisement in 2 other websites. We need to count the hits we are getting form those advertisement and like to store it in my database. Please give me an idea to do that.

Comment: What language? PHP? C#? Python? What tech? Asp.Net Webforms? Asp.Net MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I din't understood at first place the question.

You can grab the referer using PHP or link the banners to a landing page instead of to the home directly (ex: http://yoursite.com/banner.php?id=N, you can identify the referer with PHP and with the banner ID and then redirect the user to your home.

Answer (score 1):

The links to your website should have a parameter with some key that will allow you to identify the partner site.

Another approach would use the Referer http header but is less reliable.